# SpriteKit Memory Leak on static Menu scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-kit, cocos2d-x

Im experiencing memory leak on static menu scene, it appears that it happens on every scene, game scene itself but also static menu/gameover. Memory appears to be deallocated correctly (and it's reduced when scene is gone).

Those static scenes does not conatins even **update** callback defined.
It's all setup in **didMoveToView** and inside it there are couple **SKLabelNodes** and **SKSpriteNode** allocated with **spriteNodeWithImage**.

I have tried to use dealloc to monitor if scene got's deallocated correctly, and it appears to be so it seems it's not the source of the issue.

Browsing google pointed me to some other threads created on stackoverflow that
**spriteNodeWithImage**
**textureWithImage**
May cause
-Memory leaks
-weird error "CUICatalog: Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom"

So i have tried to create **UIImage imageNamed** and then put in into texture and use in SKTexture, actually it has removed CUICatalog error (which anyway, seems like a stupid message which did not been removed by apple - can anyone confirm that ?)
But according to memory leaks this didn't help at all, and anyway anything in that scene is being created once on beginning so i have no idea why this memory keeps growing and growing like 0,5mb per sec.

Looking forward for any tips.

Best regards

[image]

Comment: you are probably being lulled by the toy you are using. Try instruments. Also make certain you dont have zombie detection enabled.

Comment: Why do you mean "by the toy you are using" if you are referring to this memory chart. Actually memory leak exists, after a while of running app receive memory warning, then after a while app crashes. And NSZombie is disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually i have found the source of the problem.
It seems debugging physics makes huge memory leak

```
skView.showsPhysics = YES;
```

It's not a big problem since it happens while debugging only when **showsPhysics=YES**.

But good to know anyway.